# ObjectDisposedException when validating acceptance test data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow for our integration tests.

In the following "Then"-step, I get an ObjectDisposedException at the line `expectedPersons.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(actualPersons);`:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

```
[Then(@"the following persons should be in the database")]
public void ThenTheFollowingPersonShouldBeInTheDatabase(Table table)
{
    var expectedPersons = table.Rows.Select(expected => new Person
    {
        Id = int.Parse(expected["Id"]),
        Name = expected["Name"],
        Vorname = expected["Vorname"],
        Adressen = specflowPersonenAdressen.Where(p => p.PersonId == int.Parse(expected["Id"])).ToList()
        }).ToList();

        var actualPersons = new List<Person>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var queryCriteria = new PersonQueryCriteria
            {
                NameFilter = row["Name"],
                VornameFilter = row["Vorname"]
            };
            actualPersons.AddRange(personWorkUnit.GetPersonen(queryCriteria));
        }

        expectedPersons.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(actualPersons);
    }
}
```

The method `personWorkUnit.GetPersonen(...)` looks like this:

```
public ICollection<Person> GetPersonen(PersonQueryCriteria queryCriteria)
{
    using (var context = this.unitOfWorkContextFactory.Create())
    {
        var personRepository = this.repositoryFactory.Create<IPersonRepository>(context);
        return personRepository.GetPersons(queryCriteria).ToList();
    }
}
```

The method `personRepository.GetPersons(...)` looks like this:

```
public ICollection<Person> GetPersons(PersonQueryCriteria personQueryCriteria)
{
    var query = this.Context.GetQuery<Person>();
    query
        .Include(q => q.Adressen)
        .Include("Adressen.Adresse");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(personQueryCriteria.NameFilter))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Name == personQueryCriteria.NameFilter);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(personQueryCriteria.VornameFilter))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Vorname == personQueryCriteria.VornameFilter);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I've specifically included the navigation properties becaus as I understood, EF is using Lazy Loading.

The database looks like this:

> Person 1 ----- * PersonAdresse * ----- 1 Adresse

The models look like this:

```
 public partial class Person
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Person()
    {
        this.Adressen = new HashSet<PersonAdresse>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PersonAdresse> Adressen { get; set; }
}

public partial class Adresse
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Adresse()
    {
        this.Personen = new HashSet<PersonAdresse>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
    public int Plz { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PersonAdresse> Personen { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonAdresse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int AdresseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Adresse Adresse { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

- What could be the problem, that this exception is thrown?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where is the ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo method? Could you show us the code for it?

Comment: ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo is from FluentAssertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of lazy loading activated. Please try disabling LazyLoadingEnabled like below in the places you are using context,

```
this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false
```

Comment: That helped to fix the exception. But unfortunately, when I try to get the Persons with the `GetPersons`method from the original post, the Persons are loaded without Addresses... why is that? I do include them in the query :S

Comment: I belive person and addresses would be two seperate tables in DB and to get Addrsses along with Person you have to join both with EF.